Проблемы с отображением image в алертах telegram
На работе решили перейти на новую версию графаны, где алертинг кардинально отличается от того что используем сейчас. Подняли дев графану и начали тыкать)
С алертингом вроде разобрались, сделали красивый шаблон, но когда установили grafana-image-renderer, сталкнулись с тем что скрин с дашбордами отправляется после сообщения с алертом, то есть не вместе с алертом как в нашей продовой графане.
